# Mostrar fecha actual con formato DD-MM en Java

Tags: java, date, localtime

Necesito guardar la fecha actual en un String, formato dd-mm.

He probado con la clase LocalTime y hacer sout con SimpleDateFormat

```
LocalTime ahora = LocalTime.now();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(ahora));
```

Da error en ejecución. SimpleDateFormat solo me funciona con objetos tipo Date.

Gracias!

Comment: `LocalTime` no es una clase válida para almacenar una fecha, sólo sirve para almacenar la hora. Necesitarás `LocalDate` o, si quieres ambas, `LocalDateTime`. En cuanto al formateador, te recomiendo usar `DateTimeFormatter`. Para darle el formato que quieres a un objecto `DateTime` sería `var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");` y ya para finalizar `formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adrian, Lo que sucede es que estas confundiendo los tipos de datos, `java.time` tiene `LocalTime`, `LocalDate` y `LocalDateTime`, se diferencian de la sigueinte forma.

- `LocalTime` manejo únicamente de la parte horaria, ejemplo `13:45:30.596`.
- `LocalDate` manejo de la parte de fecha, ejemplo: `2021-06-16`
- `LocalDateTime` manejo completo de fecha y hora, ejemplo: `2021-06-16T13:45:30.608`

Esto quiere decir que a `LocalTime` no le puedes pedirle el mes, día o año, entonces para tu error debes de utilizar `LocalDate` o `LocalDateTime` y `DateTimeFormatter`, ten en cuenta que `MM` significa mes y `mm` significa minutos, para que no los confundas:

Además `SimpleDateFormat` es para utilizar con `Date`, para `LocalDateTime` y variantes se utiliza `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    DateTimeFormatter formatters = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM");
    System.out.println( dateTime.format(formatters));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Roberto, aun estoy aprendiendo Java y no tenia muy claro lo de las fechas. Un saludo!

Comment: Es normal, todos tenemos dudas al iniciar a programar, para eso es este este sitio para crear una base de datos para las dudas y problemas que otros vamos encontrando sin importar el nivel de programación.